# How transform wechat weixin link to the qr code

Tags: hyperlink, qr-code, wechat

I've got from stripe URL for payment via wechat on the back end.

It looks like this: weixin://wxpay/bizpayurl?pr=j6w0hoZ

The question is how could I transform it to the image of QR code?

I found the library on python. https://github.com/vericant/wechat_pay

Is there a version for Java?

Answer (score 0):

The link by itself has to be encoded to QRcode.
Smth like this:
cd /home/... && qrencode -l H -t PNG -o qr.png 'weixin://wxpay/bizpayurl?pr=XooE68U'